# Building footprint extraction in automated way

Tags: footprint

I am trying to extract building footprints automatically (even semi automated way will do) from 0.5mts optical imagery.

Currently my study area is Poland, however I would love to have a way that will give me an optimized result across the entire globe.

I have come across two potential solutions as listed below:

1. Using BREC4GEM software as a plugin for QGIS. However, I am not able to install the plugin in QGIS as the plugin seems to broken. Can you help with the software or the installation part?
2. Using Orfeo toolbox- I have the software working.  Can you help with any work flow on how to use Orfeo toolbox in extracting building footprints automatically?

Is there any other way to extract the building footprints automatically?

Comment: Check [segmentation](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Applications/app_Segmentation.html) in OTB